# sequences and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ such that $\|x_n\|=\|y_n\|=1$. I see in a paper the following statements: We claim that there exists a constant $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\langle x_n\; |\;y_n\rangle|\leq \theta< 1$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. To see this, suppose otherwise. By replacing $(x_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq1}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ with subsequences, we may assume that $\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}|\langle x_n\; |\;y_n\rangle|=1$. I don't understand how to prove that
  $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}|\langle x_n\; |\;y_n\rangle|=1.$$
Where $\mathcal{H}$ stands for a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$.
 And thank you.

Comment: What does $\langle x_n|y_n\rangle$ denote?

Comment: $\mathcal{H}$ stands for a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: You have not given all informations !! It is given that $|\langle x_n\; |\;y_n\rangle|\leq 1$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: Yes  because $\|x_n\|=\|y_n\|=1$ so by cauchy Schwartz we get the inequality . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that it is not true that there is a constant $\theta<1$ such that
$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq\theta <1 $ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Therfore, for every positive integer $k$, the number $\theta=1-1/k$ does not satisfy
$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq 1-1/k $ for all $n$ sufficiently large, which means that it is not true that there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ this inequality is valid. Therefore, there exists some $n_k$ such that 
$1\geq |\langle x_{n_k}|y_{n_k}\rangle|> 1-1/k $ where the l.h.s inequality from from the fact that $x_n,y_n$ are unit vectors, and in fact we can always choose $n_{k+1}>n_k$ (why?). It follows that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|\langle x_{n_k}|y_{n_k}\rangle|=1$$
as was declared.

Comment: It is not very clear for me why we can always choose $n_{k+1}>n_k$??. What means by l.h.s inequality? And thank you

Comment: I can explain it to you but I think it is better that you figure it out yourself. You are welcome.